# XSLT: How to check the specific protocol or string present in the URL

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to display this xml file following constarints

Page should have a table of employee's details.
Columns should have following headers: id, First Name, Last Name, Link Url, Salary
Table must contain details of the employees accordingly.

Condition
if the linkurl have (http:// or https:// or www)  when I am clicking the link it should open in new tab
that means - 016,024,056 should open in new tab

Other links should open same tab
ie -080, 092 should open same tab

## employee.xml

```
            <?xml version = "1.0"?>  
            <?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "employee.xsl"?>   
            <class>   
               <employee id = "016">  
                  <firstname>Aryan</firstname>   
                  <lastname>Gupta</lastname>   
                  <linkurl>https://www.aryanguptan.com/external</linkurl>   
                  <salary>30000</salary>  
               </employee>   
                    <employee id = "080">   
                  <firstname>Sam</firstname>   
                  <lastname>Alex</lastname>   
                  <linkurl>/user/internal/080</linkurl>   
                  <salary>10000</salary>   
               </employee>  
               <employee id = "024">   
                  <firstname>Sara</firstname>   
                  <lastname>Khan</lastname>   
                  <linkurl>http://www.sarakhan.com</linkurl>   
                  <salary>25000</salary>  
               </employee>   
                <employee id = "092">   
                  <firstname>John</firstname>   
                  <lastname>Samuel</lastname>   
                  <linkurl>/user/internal/092</linkurl>   
                  <salary>10000</salary>   
               </employee> 
               <employee id = "056">   
                  <firstname>Peter</firstname>   
                  <lastname>Symon</lastname>   
                  <linkurl>www.petersymon.com</linkurl>   
                  <salary>10000</salary>   
               </employee>    
            </class>
```

This is the stylesheet file

## employee.xsl

```
            <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>   

                <xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  

                <xsl:variable name="tlds">
                      <tld>http://</tld>
                      <tld>https://</tld>
                      <tld>www.</tld>      
                   </xsl:variable>

                   <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='tlds']"/>   

                   <xsl:template match = "/">          

                      <html>   
                         <body>   
                            <h2>Employee </h2>   
                            <table border = "1">   
                               <tr bgcolor = "pink">   
                                  <th>ID</th>   
                                  <th>First Name</th>   
                                  <th>Last Name</th>   
                                  <th>Link URL</th>   
                                  <th>Salary</th>   
                               </tr>   

                               <xsl:for-each select = "class/employee">                                 
                                     <tr>   
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select = "@id"/></td>   
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select = "firstname"/></td>   
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select = "lastname"/></td>  

                                        <xsl:choose> 
                                            <xsl:when test="$lookup/tld[starts-with($linkurl)]">
                                                <td><a href="{linkurl}" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select = "linkurl"/></a></td>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <td><a href="www.google.com/{linkurl}"><xsl:value-of select = "concat('www.google.com/',linkurl)"/></a></td>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>

                                        <td><xsl:value-of select = "salary"/></td>  
                                     </tr>                        
                               </xsl:for-each>   

                            </table>   
                         </body>   
                      </html>  
                   </xsl:template>    
                </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I am executing employee.xml i am getting this error in my browser

Error during XSLT transformation: An XPath function was called with the wrong number of arguments.

And also whether is it possible to reuse the varibale template seperately?
I am expecting this output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
<xsl:when test="$lookup/tld[starts-with($linkurl)]">
```

The `starts-with` function takes two parameters; the first of which is the string you wish to check starts with the second parameter. In other words, it should be this:

```
<xsl:when test="$lookup/tld[starts-with($linkurl, .)]">
```

Note this assumes you have defined the `$linkurl` variable in your stylesheet, as currently it is omitted

```
<xsl:variable name="linkurl" select="linkurl" />
```

Comment: hai Thnaks is it possible to add a sperate file for variable name "tlds" and call this 'tlds' in employee.xsl file. So i can reuse the code rit?

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="tlds">
   <tld>http://</tld>
   <tld>https://</tld>
   <tld>www.</tld>      
 </xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='tlds']"/> `

Comment: This code alone i want to write a seperate file 'globalVar.xsl' and call this file in employee.xsl.Is it possible?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question about this. Thanks